# Should I fix warnings which are only in remote debugger? | React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing an app using React Native and Expo and I have the following situation:
I have no warnings when remote debugging is disabled in Expo. But when I start remote debugging - the warning `Cannot perform a React state update on unmounted component` appears.

Does it mean that when the app runs on mobile there are no issues indeed, only when it is executing in Chrome? Or does it simply not showing when not debugging remotely? So do I need to fix this possible memory leak or is it only concerns debugging mode? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: If you post  reproducible example code, I can tailor my answer to your specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to take any warning lightly since being a developer, its our responsibility to make code as clean as it can get. Warnings may not hinder you from releasing an app but it can definitely produce some sort of bug in the long run.

In your case, it is a legitimate warning which should be fixed. You can make sure that your component is mounted before setting up any state changes. This specific check will cause no harm to your logic rather it will guard from memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is explaining to you that you have behavior that is executing in a  component state that is unaccounted for. You have components that have not mounted but are still running functions to update their state.

Depending on what these components are trying to accomplish, for class components, you can move some functionality into the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method so that it only executes if the component is mounted.